# How to limit number of colors in an image to a specific set in python

Tags: python, image, colors, python-imaging-library, png

I'm trying to create a python script that will take an image with n number of colors and reduce it to be f where f is a specified number of colors chosen by me, I found in similar questions how to get the major colors in an image, compare each pixel to them and assign the closest one. I was able to implement that but I wanted to change the script so that I could give it specific colors and check if they are first present in the image, after that I want to limit the number of pixel colors to those that I was able to find

here's what I have:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

image = Image.open('cat.png')

image_nd = np.array(image)
print(image_nd.shape)
image_colors = {}

label_colors = [
    [124, 204, 4, 255], #Grass
    [252, 172, 204, 255], #Village
    [172, 204, 52, 255], #Trees
    [156, 156, 172, 255], #Snow
    [236, 52, 252, 255], #Shrooms
    [244, 236, 196, 255], #Sand
    [116, 148, 188, 255], #Rocks
    [172, 84, 36, 255], # Red Sand
    [236, 28, 36, 255], # Lava
    [156, 220, 236, 255], #Ice
    [108, 108, 44, 255], #Dirt
    [124, 52, 204, 255], #Cobblestone
    [180, 204, 252, 255] #Water
]

image_labels = []

# This bool is used to check if the label color is already in image_labels
a = False
# For each pixel
for row in image_nd:
    for pxl in row:
        # check against the label_colors
        pxl = tuple(pxl)
        
        for color in label_colors:
            if pxl == color:
                # check if we haven't added the color to image_labels already
                for labels in image_labels:
                    if labels == color:
                        # if it's already there set the bool to be true
                        a = True
                if a == False:
                    # if we haven't added the color to image_labels then added to it
                    image_labels.append(color)

            


# this method takes the colors to be checked against in the image, and the image as a nparray
def closest(colors, image):
    colors = np.array(colors).astype(np.int32)
    image = image.astype(np.int32)
    distances = np.argmin(np.array([np.sqrt(np.sum((color - image) ** 2, axis=2)) for color in colors]), axis=0)
    return colors[distances].astype(np.uint8)

image_nd = closest(image_labels, image_nd)

aliased = Image.fromarray(image_nd)
aliased.save("pattern_2_al.png")
```

after running it though, nothing happens, It might be because the image is 11520x3840 so it might just take a long time, but I want to make sure I'm not doing anything wrong in my code or if maybe there's a better way to do this.
Any help is greatly appreciated
I apologize for any unclear bits in the question, this my first time posting a question and on top of that I'm very new to python and image processing

Here's the script that generates the image of the map with the interpolation filter:

```py
import os
import PIL.Image
import numpy as np
import sys
import png

loc_dict = {1:(0,1),
            2:(1,1),
            3:(0,0),
            4:(1,0)}

class level:
    def __init__(self, directory, image_file=None, depth = 1, x_loc=0, y_loc=0):
        self.children = []
        if image_file is None:
            image_file = directory + 'base.png'
        #make sure the image file exists
        assert os.path.isfile(image_file), 'Bad File:' + image_file
        self.image_file = image_file
        self.depth = depth
        self.x_loc = x_loc
        self.y_loc = y_loc
        #self.has_background = (0,0,0,0) in list(PIL.Image.open(self.image_file).getdata())
        for i in range(1,5):
            new_dir = directory + str(i) + '/'
            if os.path.isdir(new_dir):
                child = level(directory=new_dir, image_file=directory + str(i) + '.png', depth = depth+1,
                              x_loc = self.x_loc*2+loc_dict[i][0], y_loc = self.y_loc*2+loc_dict[i][1])
                self.children.append(child)
            else:
                self.children.append(None)
    def has_children(self):
        return any(child is not None for child in self.children);

    def num_levels(self):
        return max(1 if child is None else child.num_levels()+1 for child in self.children)

    def num_leaves(self):
        if not self.has_children():
            return 1
        else:
            return sum(0 if child is None else child.num_leaves() for child in self.children)

    def num_leaves_with_background(self):
        if not self.has_children():
            return int(self.has_background)
        else:
            return sum(0 if child is None else child.num_leaves_with_background() for child in self.children)
        
    def gen_image(self):
        if not self.has_children():
            return np.array(PIL.Image.open(self.image_file))
        else:
            images = [None if child is None else child.gen_image() for child in self.children]
            shapes = [child.shape for child in filter(lambda x: x is not None, images)]
            #make sure they're all the same
            assert [shape == shape[0] for shape in shapes], 'Bad shapes' + str(shapes)
            images = [np.zeros(shapes[0], dtype=np.uint8) if image is None else image for image in images]
            top = np.concatenate((images[0],images[1]), axis = 1)
            bottom = np.concatenate((images[2],images[3]), axis = 1)
            full = np.concatenate((top,bottom), axis=0)
            return full
    def visit(self, visitor):
        visitor.visit(self)
        for child in self.children:
            if child is not None:
                child.visit(visitor)

    def visit_leaves(self, visitor):
        if not self.has_children():
            visitor.visit(self)
        else:
            for child in self.children:
                if child is not None:

                    child.visit_leaves(visitor)

class Bounds:
    def __init__(self, x_min=sys.maxsize, x_max=0, y_min=sys.maxsize, y_max=0):
        self.x_min = x_min
        self.x_max = x_max
        self.y_min = y_min
        self.y_max = y_max

    def __str__(self):
        return '((' + str(self.x_min) + ',' + str(self.x_max) +')(' + str(self.y_min) + ',' + str(self.y_max) + '))'

                    
class find_bounds:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bounds = Bounds()

    def visit(self, node):
        self.bounds.x_min = min(self.bounds.x_min, node.x_loc)
        self.bounds.y_min = min(self.bounds.y_min, node.y_loc)
        self.bounds.x_max = max(self.bounds.x_max, node.x_loc)
        self.bounds.y_max = max(self.bounds.y_max, node.y_loc)

        
    @staticmethod
    def find_bounds(top):
        fb = find_bounds()
        top.visit_leaves(fb)
        print('Bounds:', str(fb.bounds))


        
class gen_image:
    def __init__(self, bounds):
        self.size = (bounds.x_max-bounds.x_min, bounds.y_max-bounds.y_min)
        self.bounds = bounds
        #Three dimentional array initialized with 0s 
        #The dimentions for the array are 
        #Number of columns = sizeY*384 
        #Number of rows = sizeX*384 
        #Number of z rows = 4 
        self.array = np.zeros((self.size[1]*384, self.size[0]*384, 4), dtype = np.uint8)
    def visit(self, node):
        #if this node is within these bounds...
        if (node.x_loc >= self.bounds.x_min and
            node.x_loc < self.bounds.x_max and
            node.y_loc >= self.bounds.y_min and
            node.y_loc < self.bounds.y_max):
            # initialize cur with the node image file
            cur = np.array(PIL.Image.open(node.image_file))
            self.array[(self.size[1]-(node.y_loc-self.bounds.y_min+1))*384:(self.size[1]-(node.y_loc-self.bounds.y_min))*384,
                       (node.x_loc-self.bounds.x_min)*384:(node.x_loc-self.bounds.x_min+1)*384,:] = cur
    def gen_image(top, bounds, filename):
        gi = gen_image(bounds)
        top.visit_leaves(gi)
        image  = PIL.Image.fromarray(gi.array)
        image.save(filename)

        ###################THIS IS MY CODE ABDERRAHIM JAMI####################
        
        #I tried to use the PIL convert function to reduce the number of colors in the palette. Unfortunately I don't 
        #have control over what the colors are as it only chooses the most frequent ones it can find in the image
        #Which is not always the case. There might be times where a shade of green from the antialiasing filter is more predominant than the shades of red used to represent 
        #specs of lava formations in the map....
        # result = image.convert('P', palette = PIL.Image.ADAPTIVE, colors = 13)
        # result.save(filename)



################# ANOTHER CHANGE I MADE ###########
# class find_depth:
#     def __init__(self):
#         self.max_depth=0

#     def visit(self
# for i in range(50):
#     name = str(i).zfill(3)
#     dir_name = sys.argv[1] + '/' + name + '/tl/'
#     print('Generating:', dir_name)
#     top = level(dir_name)
#     #find_bounds.find_bounds(top)
#     gen_image.gen_image(top, Bounds(x_min=14, x_max=47, y_min=21, y_max=37), dir_name + '/full-' + name + '.png')


################# ANOTHER CHANGE I MADE ###########
name = "map_myworld_BR"
dir_name = sys.argv[1] + '/' + sys.argv[2] + '/br/'
print('Generating:', dir_name)
top = level(dir_name)
#find_bounds.find_bounds(top)'




#this is another change I made... the section of the map the fullmap image is generated from is limited by these bounds values.. by editing these values it is possible 
#to center the map in the final fullmap image depeending on the orientation of the map in mapcrafter...

#WE HAVE THE MAP RENDERED FROM 4 DIFFERENT ANGLES TL, TR, BR AND BL 
# testBounds = Bounds(x_min=14, x_max=47, y_min=21, y_max=37)
# testBounds = Bounds(x_min=60, x_max=70, y_min=55, y_max=59)


#THIS IS FOR TL
# testBounds = Bounds(x_min=25, x_max=55, y_min=60, y_max=70)
#THIS IS FOR TOP-RIGHT
# testBounds = Bounds(x_min=65, x_max=90, y_min=68, y_max=78)
#THIS IS FOR BOTTOM-LEFT
# testBounds = Bounds(x_min=75, x_max=90, y_min=50, y_max=60)


#THIS IS FOR BOTTOM-RIGHT
testBounds = Bounds(x_min=90, x_max=105, y_min=50, y_max=60)

gen_image.gen_image(top, testBounds, dir_name + '/full-' + name + '.png')
print(testBounds);


#array = top.gen_image()
#print('Shape:', array.shape)
#image = PIL.Image.fromarray(array)
#image = png.from_array(array, mode='RGBA')
#image.save(sys.argv[1] + '/full.png')

#print('Level:', top.num_levels())
#print('Leaves:', top.num_leaves())
#print('Leaves with background:', top.num_leaves_with_background())
```

The script traverses an octree folder structure where every level in the tree is a zoom level, the leaf nodes in the tree contain the actual images (map sections on maximum zoom) that are used by the script to generate the map, to generate the image file the script uses the function image.FromArray()
The testBounds variable contains bounds which from my understanding delimits the area on the map from which the image is to be generated from

https://ibb.co/kSJktfQ

The image on the left is taken from the octree structure (you can see that there's no anti-aliasing applied) the screenshot on the right is taken from the image created by this script

Thanks to anyone who's dedicating his time to helping me with this. I appreciate it

Edit #3: I think I found a workaround ...
I eventually calculate the Euclidian distance between each pixel in the image and each of the label_colors I want the image to contain and assign the closest one. Like so:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
#Opens the image 
image = Image.open('full-map_myworld_12_05_21.png')
#Stores it as a numpy array
image_nd = np.array(image)
#Prints out the shape of array for debugging
print(image_nd.shape)

#Simply what the name says.. 
label_colors = [

    [124, 204, 4, 252], #Grass
    [252, 172, 204, 252], #Village
    [172, 204, 52, 252], #Trees
    [156, 156, 172, 252], #Snow
    [236, 52, 252, 252], #Shrooms
    [244, 236, 196, 252], #Sand
    [116, 148, 188, 252], #Rocks
    [172, 84, 36, 252], # Red Sand
    [236, 28, 36, 252], # Lava
    [156, 220, 236, 252], #Ice
    [108, 108, 44, 252], #Dirt
    [124, 52, 204, 252], #Cobblestone
    [180, 204, 252, 252] #Water
]

def closest(colors, image):
    #Converts elements into int32 
    colors = np.array(colors).astype(np.int32)
    image = image.astype(np.int32)
    #Finds Euclidean distance between each pixel in the image and the colors in the label_colors list
    distances = np.argmin(np.array([np.sqrt(np.sum((color - image) ** 2, axis=2)) for color in colors]), axis=0)
    return colors[distances].astype(np.uint8)



image_nd = closest(label_colors, image_nd)
#Creates the image from an array returned from closest
aliased = Image.fromarray(image_nd)
#Saves it with the given name.
aliased.save("pattern_2_al.png")
```

It does get the job done... sort of, some parts of the image where the antialiasing is applied doesn't change the color as well as I would want but it's a step closer ...
here a comparison
https://ibb.co/rmNbxw3

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed. You could see which part is slow.

Comment: Here: `if pxl == color:` you're comparing a tuple with a list, which won't work. To get this working, also convert `color` here, e.g. `if pxl == tuple(color):`. In general, if you find none of your preset colors in the image, your `closest` method fails, since `image_labels` is an empty list then. If you only find one color, e.g. `#Grass`, every pixel will be mapped to that value. Is that really what you want to achieve? Can you provide some input image along with the expected result? For arbitrary images, it's not very likely to find a sufficient number of colors for a meaningful output!?

Comment: Wouldn’t be better to have range of colors to be transformed to single colors ?

Comment: @HansHirse thank you for replying and pointing out that mistake with the `if pxl == color:`. I'm trying to generate a labeled dataset for image classification from isometric images of Minecraft maps, I have a program that labels the map for each Minecraft block type (grass block will be rendered as a green block, etc.), I'm using the PIL library to save the image, the issue is.. I added another comment to continue the comment

Comment: @HansHirse ...  for some reason, the green and all the other colors I use to label the blocks are interpolated and so I end up with an image that has more colors than I need, my idea here was to get the label colors present in the image and replace say, the different shades of green with just the one that I originally wanted. Basically, I want to remove the antialiasing effect that's being applied by the PIL library

Comment: @furas thank you for the reply, I didn't think about that

Comment: Can you upload some exemplary image? Also, is the input to the provided code here the already corrupted output of the other mentioned code? Probably, provide the interesting part of that code, too. Maybe, you don't need such "color correction", if your other code can be somehow improved to not generate interpolation artifacts!?

Comment: @HansHirse, unfortunately, I can't post any pictures directly in the question as I don't have enough reputation on my StackOverflow account, but I linked some I uploaded on Imgur, I've also included the code from the other script, this one though has passed on to me, so I'm not the author of the code you see in it and to this day I'm still trying to decypher what it's actually doing...